# convert datetime js to c#

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, datetime

How would I convert this from js to C#. I've looked but cant find anything useful.

```
var endDate = new DateTime();
endDate.setDate(startDateTime.getDate() + days);
endDate.setHours(endDateTime.getHours(), endDateTime.getMinutes(), endDateTime.getSeconds());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you don't mind sub-second precision on `endDateTime`, you could use:

```
var endDate = startDateTime.Date.AddDays(days).Add(endDateTime.TimeOfDay);
```

If you do mind, this should do the trick:

```
var offSet = new TimeSpan(days, endDateTime.Hour, endDateTime.Minute, endDateTime.Second);
var endDate = startDateTime.Date.Add(offSet);
```

Comment: @ Ani -- thanks, I'll give it a try and see what the result is.